# Yeoman generator another prompt if yes

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm making a big Yeoman generator and i wanna make something like

```
> Do you wanna continue?(y/n)
```

if yes it will continue to make a list of Choices or Question(s)
if no it'll skip

do i'll be able to do like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inquirer.js offers a [`when` option](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js#question) you can use to ignore some prompts depending on previous answers.

Although, in your case, I think it'd be cleaner to simply separate your prompts in two methods. For example `mainPrompt` and `_extraPrompt`. Then when the mainPrompt is over, check the answer for the continue question and run - or not - the extra prompts questions.

Comment: I Made this as reference for what i made https://gist.github.com/dyaa/8391829#file-index-js but doesn't work

Comment: Solved made another "Generator.prototype.askForOptionTwo" then "if (this.optionOne) {"